# How can I loop through assoc array values and put the data into a function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I build a query which i get an assoc array from. But how can I loop through them. this is what I have.

My SQL Query:

```
public static function album_display() {
        global $database;
        $sql  = "SELECT a.*, ";
        $sql .= "(SELECT photographs.filename ";
        $sql .= "FROM photographs ";
        $sql .= "WHERE photographs.albumid = a.name ";
        $sql .= "ORDER BY photographs.creation_date ASC ";
        $sql .= "LIMIT 1) ";
        $sql .= "AS filename FROM album a ";
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I use print_r() on $row the output is:

```
15Jaap1Jaap1.JPG16Jaap2Jaap4.JPG17Jaap3Jaap7.JPG18Jaap4Jaap12.JPG19Jaap5
```

I want to loop through Jaap1, Jaap2, Jaap3, Jaap 4 and put these in $albumid from the function album_path($albumid, $filename). I want to do the same wiht the JPG files. This function is in Class() Album. So is the function album_display() 
The function album_path($albumid, $filename) if called needs to output the complete album/images path en echo these to the screen. And display the images

```
public function album_path($albumid, $filename) {
        return $this->upload_dir.DS.$albumid.DS.$filename;
    }
```

How can I use foreach for this. Or is there an other better way to do it?

Kind Regards,
Coos Wolff

Comment: Can you add the raw output of the var_dump to your question _Without any editing by yourself_ please

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I put var_dump($row) in my public static function album_display() instead of echo $row the raw output is: string(2) "15" string(5) "Jaap1" string(9) "Jaap1.JPG" string(2) "16" string(5) "Jaap2" string(9) "Jaap4.JPG" string(2) "17" string(5) "Jaap3" string(9) "Jaap7.JPG" string(2) "18" string(5) "Jaap4" string(10) "Jaap12.JPG"

Answer (score 0):

Change the `select a.*`, into a `select a.albumid`. That should only return you the album id, and the filename, coming from the second `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me with there answers I finally got it working. I really appreciated your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = [];

public static function album_display() {
    global $database;
    $sql  = "SELECT a.*, ";
    $sql .= "(SELECT photographs.filename ";
    $sql .= "FROM photographs ";
    $sql .= "WHERE photographs.albumid = a.name ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY photographs.creation_date ASC ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1) ";
    $sql .= "AS filename FROM album a ";
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $my_array['albumid'][] = $row->albumid;
            $my_array['filename'][] = $row->filename;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($my_array['albumid'] as $albumid) {
    echo $albumid;
}

foreach ($my_array['filepath'] as $filepath) {
    echo $filepath;
}

album_path($my_array['albumid'], $my_array['filepath']);
```

Comment: This outputs the values I need. But how can I retrieve the values (albumid and filename which exists four times) to put into my album_path() funciton? Which takes 2 arguments $albumid(Jaap1, Jaap2, Jaap3, Jaap4) and $filename(Jaap1.JPG, Jaap4.JPG, Jaap7.JPG, Jaap12.JPG).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? You can break the sql up onto multiple lines within the quotes which makes it easier to read and also use an alias for each of the tables, again making it slightly easier to read and quicker to write.

```
<?php
    public static function album_display() {
        global $database;

        $sql  = "SELECT a.*,
            ( SELECT p.`filename`
                FROM `photographs` p
                WHERE p`.`albumid` = a.name
                ORDER BY p.`creation_date` ASC 
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS 'filename' FROM `album` a ";
        $result_set = $database->query( $sql );

        /* using object notation rather than array for ease */
        while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_object( $result_set ) ){
            $this->album_path( $rows->albumid, $rows->filename );
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It says now:  Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\jaaplangelaar\includes\album.php on line 86. So I changed $this->album_path( $rows->albumid, $rows->filename ); to Album::album_path( $rows->albumid, $rows->filename ); Now it returns: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$albumid in C:\xampp\htdocs\jaaplangelaar\includes\album.php on line 86. So it is looping but $albumid is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns one row at a time from the result set built by your query.

Each `$row` is an associative array and if you look more closely at the output of the `var_dump()` you will see that the array is a set of `key - value` pairs.

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
    //echo $row['id'];
    //echo $row['filename'];   
    //echo $row['albumid']; 

    // just to be sure add this line 
    // so we know exactly whats in $row
    print_r($row);
}
```

Sorry because you used `SELECT *` for the other fields I dont know what to call the array elements. I hope you get the basic idea.

Comment: I understand the idea. Now I am trying to get the row albumid and filename (which are four of those) into my album_path function. I tried many ways and googled it a lot. I just can't get it to work

Comment: Its really not clear what you actually want to happen next. Like you say, you funciton takes 2 scalar parameter. Added a suggesttion, this time dont edit the output of the `print_f($row)` just add it as additional info to your question _Edit the question, dont put it as a comment_